# edit two database from different sites with same form with ASP

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing some ASP pages with the following purpose.

I have two websites related to each other.
In the first one I have a form in which I insert some info. 
Those info are stored in the database of the first site.

Since the fields of the database of the other site are the same for the table i'd like to edit, is there a way to send the data to the other site and insert them into the second database just after being stored in the first one?

Database Connection

```
Set Con = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Con.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" & server.MapPath("/writable/mdb-database/mydb.mdb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open a new connection to the second database server and insert the same data to it. Use the same queries (or linq expressions or etc.) just with the new connection. I don't know how you connect to the first one, but you can connect to the second with the same method, just change the address.

Comment: so you are telling me that if I do another Con.Open "..." and I change server.MapPath("writable/mydb.mdb") with the other server address it will work properly?? is just that simple??

Comment: can you please show me how you're connecting to the database by editing your question?

Comment: you are directly connecting to the file. if the database server is running in another computer, using the server/instance name for connecting is healthier. if the file is in the same computer, you can just connect to it with the same way.

Comment: considering the 2nd DB file in another computer, could you write down how the connection lines should be???

Comment: i don't think you have the permission to do so. open/connect the related database in Visual Studio, right click and properties, there you will see connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

as a bad practice you could add a new trigger on the insert of first table, and if tow databases are not located on same server, a linked server object could help you to access each other. And now, why I labeled it as a bad practice? because the lack of manageability. scripts in database are not known as managed codes so if you do not document it properly it will be difficult to be traced by other programmers.

the best solution to the scenario is inserting tow records one by one and using TRANSACTION to insure integrity of data if both databases located on the same server ,or using DTC in a distributed scenario.

some guides to DTC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146%28VS.85%29.aspx